# Undo move of sublevel files without their directories to single flat directory

Tags: bash

### General setup

```
-root-dir<br>
---dir-tar<br>
---file<br>
---dir<br>
------dir<br>
------file<br>
---dir<br>
------dir<br>
------fil<br>
```

### Command I ran:

```
find ./dir -type f -iname "*" -exec mv {} --target-directory=dir-tar /;
```

I was in `root-dir`
(note dir-tar is inside root-dir)

### Problem

No sub-directories were moved.
All files are now listed in `dir-tar` without their subdirectories (basically unorganized mess!)

So any help is appreciated.
Is their any info on what went where?
I tried `ls -lrt` to look at dates or times, but there is no real pattern to piece it back together.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an archive of any sort, however out-of-date?  That would give you the directory structure.  You might be able to script most of the undo from that, leaving only a few cases you need to look at by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, find did what you asked it to. It found every file and moved every file. Unless you have some kind of reference to look at (backup, archive) I believe it is next to impossible to restore the original structure because as far as I know, filesystems don't have a reverse option for moving files.

In the future, it may be wise to prepent an "echo" to you command, so that you see what will happen before executing it. In this particular case, what you wanted done could be achieved with `mv dir/* tar-dir` or:

```
find /path -type d -maxlevel 1 -exec -->echo<-- mv {} /dest/ \;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks... (getting back to this post a little late).

Comment: @syntax, welcome to SU! While thanks are always appreciated, the way to thank people on the SE network is to upvote their answer.

Comment: Simple and easy, if too complicated, take break:  also thanks for echo (@terdon i was interrupted, doing it now)